# Dynamically pass in an angular.js directive template property

Tags: angularjs

How can I assign a string to the template property of an angular.js directive, by passing the string as an attribute from any element that would be consuming that directive name?

For example:

In the markup:
    
    ...

Then in the angular directive:

```
angular.module('TestModule', [])
.directive('myCustomDirective', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: 'my_template'
    };
});
```

I have tried all the strategies to bind to a directive, by the use of
'@', '=' and '&' but they only help to pass values into the template but not passing 
the template itself.

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: You are trying to pass html you have set on the scope?

Comment: You can't, AFAIK. Template is evaluated before expressions assigned to attributes are even interpolated. You need to use a link function and compile the template and add dynamically

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by New Dev, either you can compile and add your template dynamically during link function. Or you can define a fixed directive template and use ng-include to variate inner content: Like this:

```
template: "<div ng-include='templateToUse'></div>", 
scope: {templateToUse:'='}
```

Now if you pass different templateToUse from where you define the directive.

`<div my-directive template-to-use='determineTemplate()'></div>`